# jQuery Mobile -- Event Binding

Tags: javascript, events, jquery-mobile, bind

I'm trying to have jQuery-Mobile execute a piece of code each time a page is shown. However, the page is generated automatically by an underlying framework which does not set an ID. This means that I can control the javascript but not the page generation. Therefore, I'm using $.mobile.activePage to bind the event pageshow without success. Why isn't this working and what would the solution be? Thanks.

`$.mobile.activePage.bind('pageshow', function() { alert('message'); }`

Answer (score 3):

Listen to 'pagechange' event. You can get `fromPage` and `toPage` from the `pagechange` event.

```
$(document).off('pagechange');
$(document).on('pagechange', function (e, ui) {
    //triggers on page change
    console.log('from page: %o', ui.options.fromPage);
    console.log('to page: %o', ui.toPage);
});
```

Comment: How is that supposed to help me? This will register an event handler on the document object. However, I need it only on one page. Additionally, since the pages do not have IDs, I can't even check if the target page is actually the one who needs to execute the javascript code. Also, this introduces overhead since it will be running code for each page change but the script needs to execute only on one certain page.